# How do I call a specific TableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift

The first cell in this TableViewController is suppose to alert the user when their status is liked or favorited. I need to create a function so when a button is tapped, it will call this table view cell and notify them who liked their photo. I am just not sure how to call this specific table view cell. Can anybody help me out? I have searched SO and Apples Swift Documentation with no luck.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't really make much sense. You don't "call" a table view cell. A cell is just a view representing some data from your table view's data source. If the data is updated you would reload the cell.

Comment: Have you tried assigning the different cells with a specific identifier?

Comment: Well since these are prototypes, I am unsure of how to make one appear when that button is clicked.

Comment: You can create a custom tableviewcell, then send button touch's event to your viewcontroller via delegate or block

Answer (score 2):

In your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` tableview delegate method you can get the index path (row position) of the cell they tapped on and then if you've got an array of data (used to populate the tableview in the first place) you know where to look to find out which notification/activity it is:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let selectedItem = items.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as String
}
```

You can also get the cell by adding this inside the method:

```
let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the reference to the cell with `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method of UITableView.